# Shallow copy, Deep copy

Tags: javascript

```js
const Inner = function(Text) {
  this._Text = Text;
  this.Alert = () => {
    alert(this._Text["Message"]);
  }
};
const Outer = function() {
  this.Text = {
    Message: "Hi"
  };
  this.Inner = new Inner(this.Text);
  this.Alert = this.Inner.Alert;
};
const OuterObject = new Outer();
OuterObject.Alert();
OuterObject.Text["Message"] = "Hello";
OuterObject.Alert();
```

Output: Hi->Hello

```js
const Inner = function(Text) {
  this._Text = Text;
  this.Alert = () => {
    alert(this._Text["Message"]);
  }
};
const Outer = function() {
  this.Text = {
    Message: "Hi"
  };
  this.Inner = new Inner(this.Text);
  this.Alert = this.Inner.Alert;
};
const OuterObject = new Outer();
OuterObject.Alert();
OuterObject.Text = {
  Message: "Hello"
};
OuterObject.Alert();
```

Output: Hi->Hi

I was experimenting with shallow copy and deep copy in Javascript.Then I ran the above codes.
I don't understand why the former was a shallow copy and the latter a deep copy.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

After you call `new Outer();` in your first code block, you end up with both `this.Text` inside of Outer and `this._Text` within `Inner` pointing to the same object in memory, that being the object you created in `Outer`:

```js
{
  Message: "Hi"
}
```

This is due to the fact that when you pass `this.Text` to `Inner` you end up passing the reference of the above object. As a result, `this._Text` references the same object to `this.Text` refers to. This means that when you modify the `Text` object, the change is reflected also when you log `this._Text`, because both `Text` and `_Text` are referring to the *same* object.

A similar thing occurs with your second code block - before you perform `OuterObject.Text = {Message: "Hello"};` both `this._Text` and `this.Text` refer to the same object in memory (as they did in the first example), however, when you reassign `OuterObject.Text = {Message: "Hello"};`, you are creating a new object in memory (`{Message: "Hello"};`), and assigning a reference to that new object to the `.Text` property, the object that `._Text` refers to (`{Message: "Hi"}`) still remains, as all you have done is update `.Text` to point to a new object, and haven't changed the `this._Text` reference or object.

---

To explain in diagrams, in both code blocks, you initially have the following:

[image: memory diagram example of this.Text and this._Text pointing to same object in memory]

In your first code block, when you do `OuterObject.Text["Message"] = "Hello";`, you're updating the one object in memory that both `this.Text` and `this._Text` point to, meaning that when you view `this._Text.Message` you see `"Hello"` and the same with `this.Text.Message`:

[image: daigram showing the existing object in memory is updated]

In your second code block, the first diagram/situation still occurs but the second doesn't, instead, when you perform `OuterObject.Text = {Message: "Hello"};` you get the following structure:

[image: this.Text points to a new object in memory and this._Text points to the old object still]

Above, `this.Text` points to a new object created in memory, whereas `this._Text` still points to the old object, as the pointer for `this._Text` isn't changed. So logging `this._Text` still shows `"Hi"`